# Copy and Insert in d3 selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In a d3 program I need to get a node (with d3.selection) and then I want to insert in the same svg.

I know there are some functions like append, and insert, but these functions are for new elements.

```
var node = d3.select("rect#someId"); //node with some attributes and listeners
```

Now my var node got the following attributes: 
{_groups, _parents}

```
var anotherNode = d3.select("anotherNode").insert(node); //It work but it would be great a similar function or a workaround
```

Note. I need to preserve the listeners of the node

Comment: Have a look at [*"how to copy a DOM node with event listeners?"*](/q/15408394).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### New answer

D3 v5.0 introduced [`selection.clone`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_clone), which:

> Inserts clones of the selected elements immediately following the selected elements and returns a selection of the newly added clones.

Here is a demo:

```js
var copy = d3.select("#group").clone(true).attr("transform", "translate(120,100)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="200">
 <g id="group">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
  <circle cx="35" cy="40" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Note that, just as the solution in the original answer, `selection.clone` will not clone the listeners.

---

#### Original answer

Use this function to clone your selection:

```
function clone(selector) {
    var node = d3.select(selector).node();
    return d3.select(node.parentNode.insertBefore(node.cloneNode(true), node.nextSibling));
}
```

Then, you can call it with `clone("#foo")` (by ID) or `clone(".foo")` (by class).

Here is an example, where the group (one rect and one circle) with ID "group" is cloned (the translate is just to better see the clone):

```js
function clone(selector) {
    var node = d3.select(selector).node();
    return d3.select(node.parentNode.insertBefore(node.cloneNode(true),
node.nextSibling));
}

var copy = clone("#group").attr("transform", "translate(120,100)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="200">
 <g id="group">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
  <circle cx="35" cy="40" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
 </g>
</svg>
```

PS: This will not clone the listeners. Also, this function is not mine, it was written by Bostock.

Comment: I found this demo from Mike Bostock helpful, although it deals with HTML instead of SVG: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9360565. And select.clone() sounds helpful in this context: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_clone